# gradle sonar-runner setting exclusions when I set 'sonar.test.inclusions'

Tags: gradle, sonar-runner

I've got a gradle multi-project build that I'm setting the following sonarRunner extension on:

```
sonarRunner {
toolVersion = '2.4'
sonarProperties {
    property "sonar.host.url", "http://10.60.206.2:9000"
    property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:postgresql://10.60.206.2:5432/postgres"
    property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "org.postgresql.Driver"
    property "sonar.jdbc.username", "postgres"
    property "sonar.jdbc.password", "postgres"
    property "sonar.scm.provider", "svn"
    property "sonar.sources", "src"
    property "sonar.tests", "$projectDir/some/existing/dir"
    property "sonar.test.inclusions", "**/**"
}}
```

When I do so I see the below in the output which inevitably leads to no files being indexed. Has anyone seen this before?

17:15:31.130 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US

17:15:31.131 INFO  - Index files

17:15:31.141 INFO  - Excluded sources:

17:15:31.141 INFO  -   **/**

17:15:31.141 INFO  - Included tests:

17:15:31.141 INFO  -   **/**

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, everything you will set in sonar.test.inclusions will automatically be set in both :

- Included tests
- Excluded sources

You should limit the scope of sonar.test.inclusions to a subset of files , e.g.
**/*.spec.js

Please let me know if you fixed it in any way, I'm also facing (different) issues configuring this..